# Trying to install a rails app with Capistrano 3 and rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, rbenv

I have a VPS setup with Ruby 2.1.1 installed and the same version is installed locally. My dev machine running 14.04 Ubuntu reports ruby -v = ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux] and rbenv -v = rbenv 0.4.0-97-gfe0b243.

I originally installed ruby on the server using knife solo but it seems like capistrano wants to take care of this.

When I run cap staging deploy I get an error

```
rbenv: cap: command not found
The `cap' command exists in these Ruby versions:  2.1.0
```

Gemfile

```
group :development do
 gem 'capistrano', github: 'capistrano/capistrano', ref: 'master'
 gem 'capistrano-rails', github: 'capistrano/rails', ref: 'master'
 gem 'capistrano-bundler'
 gem 'capistrano-rbenv', "~> 2.0"
end
```

Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```

deploy.rb

```
set :rbenv_type, :system
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.1'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}
set :rbenv_roles, :all # default value
```

gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.1 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 76) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/mark/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /home/mark/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin
```

Comment: did you try `rbenv rehash` to make rbenv generate a binary shim for capistrano.

Comment: Yes, it made no difference.

Comment: `gem 'capistrano', '3.2' gem 'capistrano-rails', '1.1' ` why did you point master branch

Comment: I simply read somewhere to try that.

Comment: did you try without pointing master branch and no hope?

Comment: I used the gem versions you gave and now it says ERROR rbenv: 2.1.1 is not installed or not found in /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1 but still reports ruby 2.1.1 as installed

Comment: ohhoo hoo got it you did not install rbenv correctly please follow this https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/blob/master/README.md

Comment: `rbenv versions` try this and let me know

Comment: rbenv versions
  system
  2.1.0
* 2.1.1 (set by /home/mark/.rbenv/version)

Comment: I installed rbenv exactly as outlined in this README.

Comment: I ran rbenv local 2.1.1 but no difference.\

Comment: you got the error ERROR rbenv: 2.1.1 is not installed or not found in /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1 it means it is not installed properly show me `gem env`

Comment: I added gem env to the question in an edit.

Comment: please do `bundle exec gem install` and `bundle exec cap install`...after setting local rbenv 2.1.1

Comment: gem install did nothing (no gem specified) and cap install just replaced my deploy files.

Comment: This time cap deploy ran successfully without any rbenv settings in the deploy file.

Comment: ok can I make it a post and expect acceptance from you

Comment: I need to try a more comprehensive deploy procedure as the default won't suffice.

Comment: I get error: Don't know how to build task  deploy:compile_assets_locally' but I have the task under lib/capistrano/tasks

Comment: Same error, I am using the talkingquickly git. https://github.com/TalkingQuickly/capistrano-3-rails-template

Comment: I had problems with rbenv in the past too , had to switch to rvm . Works like a charm .

Answer (score 11):

Was also struggling with this problem for a long time. @Darmen's answer pointed me into the right direction:

1) Set the path for rbenv in Capfile. For Capistrano 3.2.1, this is:

```
set :rbenv_custom_path, '/home/deploy/.rbenv/'
```

Note (maybe obvious) that it has to be the path on the server, find it with:

```
which rbenv
```

(compare https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv for rbenv_custom_path syntax - slightly different from @Darmen's answer)

2) Set the correct rbenv version in capfile, e.g.,

```
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.2'
```

For me, I did not have to use the complete ruby version. It has to match the directory name in /.rbenv/versions

Hope that helps - took me ages... ;-)

Comment: If i set that version of ruby, capistrano stops and gives me warning:        WARN  rbenv: 2.2.8 is not installed or not found in /home/unicorn/.rbenv/versions/2.2.8 on 'SERVER'

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem setting `:rbenv_path`. 
Yours should be:

```
set :rbenv_path, '/home/mark/.rbenv/'
```

I also had to set the complete ruby version, like this:

```
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.1-p76'
```

Answer (score 0):

try those commands from your dev machine:

```
cd /path/to/your/application/root
gem uninstall capistrano
gem uninstall capistrano-rails
gem uninstall capistrano-bundler
gem uninstall capistrano-rbenv
# select "All versions" everytimes
bundle
# Verify that all capistrano gems are installed
rbenv rehash
```

Then try `cap staging deploy` again

Comment: nope, same ERROR rbenv: 2.1.1 is not installed or not found in /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1

Comment: what are the output of `rbenv versions` and `ls /usr/local/rbenv/versions`? (run both from your app root directory)

Comment: system
  2.1.0
* 2.1.1 (set by /home/mark/s/.ruby-version)

Comment: /usr/local/rbenv/versions: No such file or directory

Comment: Perhaps the `.ruby-version` file is creating a problem, let's remove it temporarily. `cd` into your app root directory, then `mv .ruby-version .old.ruby-version` then try again all commands from my original message

Comment: and by simply running `bundle exec cap staging deploy` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Ruby 2.1.0, seems that the problem is caused by some compatibility issue with 2.1.1.

Or try to update Capistrano to the [latest release](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) (if you haven't yet done).

Answer (score 0):

Is possible that you need run `deploy:setup_config` and then just a straight up deploy may work.

`namespace :logs do
  desc "tail rails logs" 
  task :tail_rails do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "tail -f #{shared_path}/log/#{fetch(:rails_env)}.log"
    end
  end
end`