# Error when compiling assets on the production server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets, capistrano3

I tried to deploy my Rails application with Capistrano, and got the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_h' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the stack trace, which looks like it may be a Sprockets issue, but I can't figure out why:

```
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-es6-0.9.0/lib/sprockets/es6.rb:14:in `configuration_hash'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-es6-0.9.0/lib/sprockets/es6.rb:40:in `configuration_hash'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-es6-0.9.0/lib/sprockets/es6.rb:44:in `initialize'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-es6-0.9.0/lib/sprockets/es6.rb:21:in `new'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-es6-0.9.0/lib/sprockets/es6.rb:21:in `instance'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-es6-0.9.0/lib/sprockets/es6.rb:34:in `call'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `default'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `default'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:225:in `block in stat_tree'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `block in stat_directory'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `each'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `stat_directory'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:224:in `stat_tree'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:168:in `compile'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/var/www/paperless_office/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

This is my local environment:

```
OSX 10.11.3
Ruby 2.1.3p242
Rails 4.1.0
Rake 10.3.2
Sprockets-Rails 2.3.3
Capistrano 3.4.0
```

This is my production environment:

```
Centos 5
ruby 2.1.3p242 (managed by rbenv)
```

My currently installed gems are:

```
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
bundler (1.11.2)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
test-unit (2.1.3.0)
```

I have been able to run:

```
gem install bundler
```

However, if I run:

```
gem install rails
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Service Unavailable 503 (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rack)
```

Is this is linked to my initial question?

Comment: Are you sure this wasn't a brief glitch with the Rubygems site?

Comment: "`undefined method 'to_h' for nil:NilClass`" doesn't tell us much. It should also tell you the line number and file it's occurring in. You have an uninitialized value but we have no idea what it'd be.

Comment: You post unuseful part of log, and this part was run under ruby 1.9.1. Maybe this is the catch?

Comment: As previously mentioned by Mike, Capistrano appears to be running a different Ruby. Maybe [this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361546/trying-to-install-a-rails-app-with-capistrano-3-and-rbenv) you?

Comment: @David K-J Thanks, that post appears like it may solve the issue. I don't have access to the server again until Thursday, so will try then.

Comment: @tadman No, there may well have a been a glitch with the ruby gems site, but after managing to install rails manually on the server, I tried to deploy again, with the same issue.

Comment: @the Tin Man I know "undefined ....." doesn't say much, hence why I posted the output pointing to: .../gems/sprockets-es6-0.9.0/lib/sprockets/es6.rb:14:in `configuration_hash' - line 14 of sprockets/es6?

Comment: @Mike Belyakov I posted the output from running the failing cap production deploy task, and was aware I may need to post additional info hence why I stated "let me know if there's something else I can add to help" - except that has been edited out by the Tin Man!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this, the problem was fixed thanks to the link posted by @DavidK-J which pointed me in the right direction. I needed to update the cap files with the settings for rbenv as follows:

Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
```

deploy.rb

```
set :rbenv_type, :system
set :rbenv_path, '~/.rbenv'
set :rbenv_ruby, "2.1.3"
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}
set :rbenv_roles, :all
```

I then had to update passenger's config with the path to rbenv which in my case was:

```
~/.rbenv
```

HTH someone else.

Paul